# Push Pointer of Element into Stack

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to push a pointer of my element into the stack so it would return a pointer instead of the element.

Based on my limited understanding it's returning the element but not the pointer.

```
typedef struct Stack
{
    int capacity;
    int size;
    TLDNode* elements;
}Stack;


void push(Stack *S,TLDNode *element)
{

    S->elements = element;
    S->size = S->size + 1;
    return;
}



 Stack *S;
    S = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    S->elements = ( TLDNode *)malloc(sizeof( TLDNode)*100);
    S->size = 0;
    S->capacity = 100;

    PUSHTOSTACK(tld->head, S);
```

void PUSHTOSTACK(TLDNode *root,Stack *S) {

```
    PUSHTOSTACK(S,root);
```

}

Comment: `S->size = S->size + 1;` can be simplified to `S->size += 1;` or even `S->size++;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `elements` member of your stack struct has type `TLDNode*`, which is equivalent to an array of `TLDNode`s. What you want is an array of *pointers to* `TLDNode`s, so you need another `*` in there:

```
typedef struct Stack
{
    int capacity;
    int size;
    TLDNode** elements;
}Stack;
```

Technically this is just a *pointer to a pointer to a `TLDNode`*, but this is basically equivalent to an array of pointers, as demonstrated by the following code snippet:

```
TLDNode *node_array[10]; // Array of 10 pointers to TLDNodes
TLDNode **elements = node_array; // node_array is assignable to elements
```

Comment: @FlyingAtom - You don't need to (and arguably shouldn't) cast the result of `malloc` in C. Try this: `S->elements = malloc(sizeof(*S->elements)*100);`

Comment: @FlyingAtom - You should really only ask one question per question.... But your types obviously don't match. They don't match because you're trying to replace *the whole elements array* with a *single* element. What you probably want to do is set the *last* element in the array to the given element. `S->elements[S->size-1] = element;`